# Pure AS3 AIR map for mobile app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

The iOS/Android app I am building requires a map component and just wondering what experts here would recommend using?

The app is being developed using pure AS3 and come across MapQuest. I only really need to be able to drop multiple markers and click markers for information. No directions, search etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using a [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) instance with the HTML version of Google Maps.
You should be able to find helpful articles on the web. Sample: http://www.igorcosta.org/?p=350
Anyway, this might get tricky. :-/

Answer (score 0):

I think Google Maps is still a good idea, but I’m not sure if it will work on mobile:
http://www.gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=104

Beware that Google Maps API for Flash is deprecated.
Note (form [Google Maps API page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/flash/)):

> The Google Maps API for Flash has been officially deprecated as of September 2, 2011. The API will continue to work until September 2, 2014. We encourage you to migrate your code to version 3 of the Maps JavaScript API.

If not, you'll probably have to create a native extension.